# Alternate solutions to querying a mysql database with 18mil+ rows

Tags: mysql

Trying to query a mysql table that has over 18 million rows. All I need is a simple:

```
select date, url, count(*) from table
where date > '2018-01-01' and date < current_date
```

But it crashes after 15-20 minutes. I tried connecting to db in python using pandas module and then appending individual day's worth of data to an empty data frame. But still sitting twiddling my thumbs...

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import time

conn = pymysql.connect(...)

result = []
for date in pd.date_range(start='01/01/2019', end=pd.to_datetime(time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))):
    query = ("select * from table where time >= '{}' and time < '{}'").format(date, date + pd.DateOffset(days=1))
    df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
    result.append(df)
pd.concat(result,axis=0)
print(result)
```

What are my options in getting this data out?
Main aim is to get this data into Tableau and take it from there...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by " it crashes after 15-20 minutes"?

Comment: Just to throw it out there, you're not dealing with a lot of data here.  MySQL shouldn't have any problem digging through 18 million rows, and it shouldn't take 20 minutes to do it.  Are you actually running that query from python or from the sql client or some other client?

Comment: Apologies, what I meant is that MySQL loses connection or something like that (can't remember the exact wording)

Comment: @DanFarrell - ran it from sql client (SQLyog, Mysql workbench, DBeaver) and then from python, all of which continuing running for relatively extended periods of time

Comment: Do you have an index on column `date` ?

Comment: As GMB said, most likely the site is not indexed on the 'date' field, and that can cause a crash.  add `EXPLAIN` to the front of your query and it will show you if it is using any special indexes.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code contains potential [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you don't [properly prepare your statement](http://bobby-tables.com/python). Never use string interpolation with `{}` and `format`, instead pass through the arguments as a tuple to `execute`.

Comment: getting this in the extra column when using `explain`: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort. And yes there is an index on `time` column (should be time and not date).

Comment: Maybe it crashes by running out of memory? Are you monitoring memory usage with a tool like `top` or `htop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used python to create a for loop querying and summarising a day's worth of data from the "unqueryable" table and appended it to a csv which I then connected to the BI tool. Also tried creating a new table in the db with some indexes and then for looped the same way but appending to the table.

Answer (score 3):

I started a mysql server in docker like this, just using the defaults:

```
docker run -d --rm --name mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true mysql
```

And created database like this:

```
docker exec -it mysql mysql -e 'create database if not exists test'
```

And then connect interactive session like this:

```
docker exec -it mysql mysql test
```

I then filled it with 32 million some random dates by running this...

```
INSERT into dates select date(from_unixtime(rand()*unix_timestamp(now())) );
```

and then running this a few dozen times:

```
INSERT into dates select date(from_unixtime(rand()*unix_timestamp(now())) ) from dates;
```

Now I have almost twice as many dates as you do:

```
mysql> explain select * from dates;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dates | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 33497947 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Finally I can demonstrate how quickly I can search through the table:

```
mysql>  select count(*), d from dates where d between '2001-01-01' and '2001-12-31' group by d order by d desc;  
....
365 rows in set (4 min 31.17 sec)
```

Makes sense, there were a few thousand results for every day in 2001.  (Remember these dates are randomly distributed between 1970 - epoch - and now).

No indexes or anything and no sql tuning.  Took 4.5 minutes.  Hopefully that gives you a baseline for expectations on your server and query performance.